# Replace mysql.connector-function with reading csv/tsv data

Tags: python, mysql

I would like to run a large python script programmed by someone else (https://github.com/PatentsView/PatentsView-Disambiguation to be precise). At numerous times during the execution of this code, python connects to a mysql database in order to read some data. The problem is that I

a) cannot get a mysql installation on the server I use. Being only a guest at the institution whose computers I use, I cannot really influence IT to change this

b) would like to alter the code as little as possible, since I have very little python experience

The original code uses a function granted_table() that returns a mysql.connector.connect(...), where host, user, password etc. are given in the dots. My idea is to switch out this function with one that reads in TSV files instead, which I have all stored on my machine. This way, I do not have to go over the long script and fiddle around with it (I have almost no experience with python and might mess something up without realizing it).

I have tried a few things already and it almost works, but not quite. The reproducible example follows:

First, there is the original function that accesses mysql, which has to go

```
def granted_table(config):
    if config['DISAMBIGUATION']['granted_patent_database'].lower() == 'none':
        logging.info('[granted_table] no db given')
        return None
    else:
        logging.info('[granted_table] trying to connect to %s', config['DISAMBIGUATION']['granted_patent_database'])
        return mysql.connector.connect(host=config['DATABASE']['host'],
                                       user=config['DATABASE']['username'],
                                       password=config['DATABASE']['password'],
                                       database=config['DISAMBIGUATION']['granted_patent_database'])
```

Second, the function that tries to call the above function to read in data (I shortened and simplified it but kept the structure as I understand it. This version of the function actually only prints whatever data it receives): I do not want to change this if at all possible

```
def build_granted(config):
    cnx = granted_table(config)
    cursor = cnx.cursor()
    query = "SELECT uuid, patent_id, assignee_id, rawlocation_id, type, name_first, name_last, organization, sequence FROM rawassignee"
    cursor.execute(query)
    for rec in cursor:
        print(rec)
```

Third, there is my attempt at a new function granted_table(config) which will behave like the old one but not access mysql

```
def granted_table(config):
    return(placeholder())
    

class placeholder:
    def cursor(self):
        return conn_to_data()

class conn_to_data:
    def execute(self,query): # class method
        #define folder etc
        print(query)
        filename = "foo.tsv"
        path ="/share/bar/"
        file=open((path+filename))
        print(file.read(100))
        return file
```

Now, if I execute all of the above and then run

```
config="test"
build_granted(config)
```

the code breaks with

```
"Type Error: conn_to_data object is not iterable",
```

so it does not access the actual data as intended. However, if I change the line `cursor.execute(query)` to `cursor=cursor.execute(query)` it works as intended. I could do that if there is really no better solution, but it seems like there must be. I am a python newb, so maybe there even is a simple function/class that is intended for this and one of you can point it out. You might realize that the code currently always opens the same file, without actually interpreting the query. This is something I will still have to fix later, once it even works at all. It seems to me to be a somewhat messy but conceptually simple string-parsing problem, but if some of you have a smart idea, it would also be a huge help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A FAR EASIER solution would be to use `sqlite3` instead of `mysql.connector`.  The syntax is essentially the same, and all those SQL commands will just work.

Comment: Remember that an SQL `cursor.execute()` iterator returns a list of tuples, with the columns as separate entries in the tuple.  Your `execute` is returning the file.  That iterator returns a list of strings, one string per line.  There are no fields.  You COULD change `conn_to_data` to do `for line in file:` / `yield line.strip().split()` to simulate the other.

Comment: If you want to go down the tsv route (and [sqlite3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html) is probably going to be simpler to swap in, as suggested above), consider using the [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I will look into both options. If one of you would like to make an answer, I will accept that and close the question